# About action of the open Method(MySQL, Connector/Net)

Tags: c#, mysql

First of all, I have been started to studying the `C#` from 6 months ago and I'm not good at English.
So I'm sorry if I say something that you cannot understand.

Now, I'm developing the application with C# that ONLY connect to MySQL server(both of remote and local).
And I use a MySql.Data.Client package, it's `version 8.0.12.`
This ONLY means "I don't send any queries. I want to find that I can connect to server using a UserName and Password.".

Then, I wrote this code. And I have two questions, and I want to get any advises.

```
sendCommand = string.Format("host={0}; userid={1}; password={2}; SslMode=none;", pIPAddress.ToString(), mOption1, mOption2);

MySqlConnection mysqlConnention = new MySqlConnection(sendCommand);
mysqlConnention.Open(); 

if (mysqlConnention.State.ToString() == "Open")
{
      result = true;
}

mysqlConnention.Close();
```

Q1
The application should not send unnecessary packets to server.
However I found it from WireShark and it's "show variable" command.
I tried to change some properties about ConnectionString(in this code, it's called "send Command") because I want not to send "show variable" command. (for example, ChacheServerProperties=true, AllowBatch=false, and so on...)

Can I connect without "show variable" command?

Q2
(It's soloved but I cannot find the causion)
When I started developing this application, I used MySql.Data.Client 8.0.11.
But in that time, the MySqlConnection.Open Method was taken a long time for connection to server.(It was about 7~10 second.)

The network problems was none, and I was able to connect using cmd.exe without a long time.(It was not taken a second.)
I tried any patterns, changed server to connect, restarted OS(both of the application side and server side), changed ConnectionString properties).
MySQL server was not dying and It looked like the cause is not in MySQL server and network.(Getting the application "ServerGreeting" packet from server was no time but next action that the application send "LoginRequest" packet to server was taken a long time.)

However I was not able to slove this problem. But I updeted MySql.Data.Client version to 8.0.12, I can slove!
Is this problem caused by MySql.Data.Client 8.0.11?
And have I any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The application should not send unnecessary packets to server. … Can I connect without "show variable" command?

You can, by using an alternative ADO.NET library: [MySqlConnector](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector). It sends a lot fewer packets when opening the connection (but it may not send the absolute minimum possible).

> But in that time, the MySqlConnection.Open Method was taken a long time for connection to server.(It was about 7~10 second.) … Is this problem caused by MySql.Data.Client 8.0.11?

This sounds very much like MySQL [bug 80030](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=80030), which is a bug in 8.0.11. That case says it's going to be fixed in 8.0.13, not 8.0.12, but perhaps Oracle changed their release plans after making that comment.

This could also be fixed by using MySqlConnector, which never used an inefficient WMI query that was causing the performance problem in MySql.Data.

Comment: Mr. Bradley
Thanks your advise!! Now, I'm checking the action this library. The sending packet is no problem (this packet size and amount is allowed this application's user.)
But I can't close connection to MySQL server.  I did the close Method, however the connection is not closed.
And It is recognized as RequestUnknown(Malformed Packet).

What is my missing? What should I edit my code?

Oh, I checked announcement of Oracle's bug fixed. But I didn't check bug report from users.
Your comment was very useful for me. I think I need wait for a while Oracle's comment.

Comment: Sorry, I want to ask more question.
After I installed this library, I looked many folders. (System.Memory.4.5.0, System.Numerics.Vectors.4.4.0, and so on...)
I want to reduce the modules (especially, about .dll file) as possible.
If my code is only above, what modules can I reduce?

Comment: When pooling is enabled (the default), calling `MySqlConnection.Close()` doesn't actually close the connection, but simply returns it to an in-memory pool. (This typically greatly improves efficiency.) To force the connection to actually close, add `Pooling=false` to the connection string.

Comment: @siksmtt Those libraries are the current dependencies for MySqlConnector on all platforms except `netcoreapp2.1` (see "Dependencies" at https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/). If you can target `netcoreapp2.1` then you can avoid them; otherwise, they're currently required. (Your only other workaround would be to compile from source, but removing those dependencies would require a lot of work.)

Comment: Mr. Bradley Thanks your advise. I checked about 'Pooling=false'. It looks do action what I hope. I'm very glad. Then, I understand that reducing modules is not safety and high costs. So I'm considering to use this library. Thank you.